# `with` template tag with logical comparison result as value

Tags: django, templates, with-statement

Is there a way to assign a logical value from a comparison to a variable in the current context?

I tried :

```
{% with hidden=forloop.counter > 4 %}
  {% include "path/to/template.html" %}
{% endwith %}
```

And it didn't work because that causes a syntax error. But perhaps there is just a syntax I don't know?

So far I do something like this :

```
{% if forloop.counter > 4 %}
  {% with hidden=True %}
    {% include "path/to/template.html" %}
  {% endwith %}
{% else %}
  {% include "path/to/template.html" %}
{% endif %}
```

And it works, But it looks dirty to me.

Answer (score 0):

The `include` template tag [allows you to pass extra context](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#include)

```
{% if forloop.counter > 4 %}
  {% include "path/to/template.html" with hidden=True %}
{% else %}
  {% include "path/to/template.html" %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: That's true and that's even simpler. But Could you then directly somehow put the comparison step in the include tag? (that's more about that)

Comment: How are you using "hidden" in the included template? You could pass the count into the included template "with count=forloop.counter"

Comment: I use it as a boolean value in order to add or not a class to an element in the included template.
But if there is no way to put the comparison step in a tag argument I'll stick to the if/else method.